# Android - Custom dialog boxes layout problem

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, dialog

I have a custom dialog box displaying some text and a image underneath.

The text is made up of a few lines and despite messing around with all the XML layout stuff millions of times, the image at the bottom is always overlapping half/some of the text. How can I tweak it so it appears underneath and after the text has finished?

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
          />

<ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_below="@+id/image"
        android:layout_height="200px">          

    <TextView  android:id="@+id/text"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:textColor="#FFF"
             />

</ScrollView>     

<ImageView android:id="@+id/image2"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android1:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

Items are set inside a RelativeLayout setting.

Comment: It's easier to help you out if you add your xml layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wrap your TextView and ImageView inside a RelativeLayout you can set the ImageView to display below the TextView.

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/image2"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:layout_below="@+id/ScrollView01"/>
```

EDIT:
I saw that you had set android1:layout_alignParentBottom="true", is it a typo with the android1 and not android? Shouldn't it be android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"?

Comment: Thank you, adding that line at the bottom did the trick, and yes the "1" was a typo at my end when copying the code into the text window.